# Getting derived class from a DB query

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa

I have designed my database to use the inheritance strategy of **Table Per Class** where the common fields exists in the derived tables as well as in the parent table. Some simple model would look like this.

**Vehicle.java**

```
@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.TABLE_PER_CLASS)
public class Vehicle {

    @Id @GeneratedValue
    private int id;

    private String name;

    private String brand;

}
```

**Car.java**

```
@Entity
public class Car extends Vehicle {

    private String oil;

}
```

**Bike.java**

```
@Entity
public class Bike extends Vehicle {

    private String frame;

}
```

Now, I would like to have a unified `VehicleRepository` for all kinds of `Vehicle` objects, including `Car` and `Bike`.

The repository could look something like this.

**VehicleRepository.java**

```
@Repository
public interface VehicleRepository extends CrudRepository<Vehicle, Integer> {

    @Query("SELECT v FROM Vehicle e WHERE v.vehicleId = ?1")
    public Vehicle findById(Integer vehicleId);

}
```

So I'd like to be able to do something like following.

```
int carId = 3; // I know that in the DB there's a car with that ID
int bikeId = 7; // I know that in the DB there's a bike with that ID

// the important part
Car car = (Car) repo.findById(carId);
Bike bike = (Bike) repo.findById(bikeId);

// now I want to be able to call:
car.getOil();
bike.getFrame();
```

The question is: would this work and is this a good pattern to do it?

Comment: why dont you try it?

Answer (score 0):

You can include all the fields in the `Vehicle` and try to use [projections](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#projections) for `Car` and `Bike`.

```
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.TABLE_PER_CLASS)
public class Vehicle {

    @Id @GeneratedValue
    private int id;

    private String name;

    private String brand;

    private String oil;

    private String frame;

}
```

For `Car` and `Bike` you can use projections:

```
public interface VehicleProjection {
    public int getId();
    public String getBrand();
    public String getName();
}

public interface Car extends VehicleProjection {
    public String getOil();
}

public interface Bike extends VehicleProjection {
    public String getFrame();
}
```

And your repository should look like this:

```
public interface CarRepository extends Repository<Vehicle, Integer> {
    public Car findById(Integer carId);

}
```

Same for `Bike` repository